# Match any node in XML document using XSLT even if I don't know the names of the nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How do I transform a XML doc using XSTL when I don't know the names of the nodes. So basically it should work universally, with any XML document.

Let's say I got this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="transform.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<!DOCTYPE cinema [
<!ELEMENT a (b*)>
<!ELEMENT b (c,d,e)>
<!ELEMENT c (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT d (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT e (#PCDATA)>
]>

<cinema>
<movie>
    <actor>Some actor</actor>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <year>Some year</year>
</movie>
</cinema>
```

How would I create an HTML table out of this? I know I can match the root element like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Then I select all movies like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
```

But how to I know get one row for each movie with three columns for actor, title & year? Especially since the XML file (movie) should be able to maybe only have 2 children or 5.

+++EDIT+++

If I do this:

```
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</tr>
```

I get each movie's details in one row. This is almost close to what I want to achieve. But how to I spread out the movie details over three columns in that row?

Comment: Do you need the details to line up? E.g. does the actor, if present, always need to be in the same column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you will always have three levels of elements (root, children and grandchildren) then something like this should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body><xsl:apply-templates /></body></html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table><xsl:apply-templates /></table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates /></tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `/` template matches the *document node*, `/*` matches first-level element children of the document node (i.e. the root element of the document), `/*/*` matches second-level children, etc.

`<xsl:apply-templates/>` (with no `select`) will apply matching templates to all the child nodes of the current node, which includes child elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions.  As a result, you may need the root template to be

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body><xsl:apply-templates select="*" /></body></html>
  </xsl:template>
```

to select only child *elements*.

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks so much!! And yes, I do wanted to do for XML documents with three levels of elements.

Answer (score 1):

**sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cinema>
  <movie>
    <actor>Some actor</actor>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <year>Some year</year>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <actor>Someother actor</actor>
    <title>Someother title</title>
    <year>Someother year</year>
  </movie>
</cinema>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <tr>
              <th>actor</th>
              <th>title</th>
              <th>year</th>
            </tr>
          </xsl:if>
          <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="actor|title|year">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>actor</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>year</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some actor</td>
    <td>Some title</td>
    <td>Some year</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Someother actor</td>
    <td>Someother title</td>
    <td>Someother year</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="movie">
 <!-- Specify your tr-producing code here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But what if I have a XML doc where its not called movie but movies. I basically try to create something that would work with _any_ xml document.